# How do I set up my Project to not get 'connection reset by peer'

Tags: docker, symfony, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am trying to integrate Stripe to my Symfony project. Payment is possible, but I am stuck at implementing a Webhook to keep my payment database updated.
The Stripe CLI always returns '[ERROR] Failed to POST: Post "https://phpfpm:9000/webhook/stripe": read: connection reset by peer'.
Im completly new to Webhooks, Docker and pretty much anything with Server.

my docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: "3.9"

x-phpfpm-default-config: &phpfpm-default-config
    build:
        context: ./.docker/php
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/app:cached
        - ./.docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:cached
        - ./.docker/php/ssmtp.conf:/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf:cached
        - ./.docker/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini:cached
        - ./.docker/php/conf.d/opcache.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini:cached
        # - $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent
    environment:
        XDEBUG_CONFIG: ${XDEBUG_CONFIG}
        XDEBUG_MODE: ${XDEBUG_MODE:-debug}
        PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=parkservice.test"

services:
    db:
        image: postgres:latest
        restart: on-failure
        volumes:
            - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            - ./.docker/postgres/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
            POSTGRES_DB: database
            POSTGRES_USER: user

    phpfpm:
        <<: *phpfpm-default-config
        restart: on-failure
        depends_on:
            - db

    nginx:
        image: nginx:alpine
        depends_on:
            - phpfpm
        restart: on-failure
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/app:cached
            - ./.docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:cached
            - ./.docker/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:/etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:cached
            - ./.docker/nginx/ssl/selfsigned.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt:cached
            - ./.docker/nginx/ssl/selfsigned.key:/etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key:cached
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"

    stripe-cli:
        image: stripe/stripe-cli
        command: ["listen", "--forward-to", "https://phpfpm:9000/webhook/stripe", "--api-key", "secret", "--skip-verify"]
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/app:cached
        depends_on:
            - phpfpm

volumes:
    postgres-data: {}

networks:
    default:
        name: henned
```

and this is my function + route

```
#[Route('/webhook/stripe', name: 'webhook.stripe', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function consume(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        Stripe::setApiKey(getenv('STRIPE_SECRET'));
        $endPointSecret = getenv('STRIPE_WH_SECRET');
        $payload  = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $sigHeader = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
        $event = null;
        $log = new Logger('stripe.webhook');

        try {
            $event = Webhook::constructEvent(
                $payload, $sigHeader, $endPointSecret
            );
        } catch(UnexpectedValueException $e) {
            // Invalid payload
            http_response_code(400);
            $log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('../../../var/logs/dev.log', Level::Warning));
            $log->warning('Warning: ' . $e->getMessage());
            $log->error($e->getMessage());
            exit();
        } catch(SignatureVerificationException $e) {
            // Invalid signature
            http_response_code(400);
            $log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('../../../var/logs/dev.log', Level::Warning));
            $log->warning('Warning: ' . $e->getMessage());
            $log->error($e->getMessage());
            exit();
        }
        $session = $event->data->object;

        switch ($event->type) {
            case 'checkout.session.async_payment_failed':
                $booking = $entityManager->getRepository(Booking::class)->findOneBy(['stripeId' => $session->id]);
                $booking->setStatus('failed');
                $entityManager->flush();
                break;
            case 'checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded':
                $booking = $entityManager->getRepository(Booking::class)->findOneBy(['stripeId' => $session->id]);
                $booking->setStatus('paid');
                $entityManager->flush();
                break;
            case 'checkout.session.completed':
                if ($session->payment_status === 'paid') {
                    $booking = $entityManager->getRepository(Booking::class)->findOneBy(['stripeId' => $session->id]);
                    $booking->setStatus('paid');
                    $entityManager->flush();
                }
                break;
            // ... handle other event types
            default:
                echo 'Received unknown event type ' . $event->type;
        }
        return new JsonResponse(['status' => 'success']);
    }
```

docker ps

```
afa5d7e4994b   stripe/stripe-cli        "/bin/stripe listen …"   16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes                                                      parkservice-stripe-cli-1
8f8bfc2f4576   nginx:alpine             "/docker-entrypoint.…"   16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp           parkservice-nginx-1
27d0bc6a3d00   parkservice-phpfpm       "docker-php-entrypoi…"   16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes   9000/tcp                                           parkservice-phpfpm-1
6dd1bc66ef2f   postgres:latest          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp                             parkservice-db-1
1d57e5edf7ec   schickling/mailcatcher   "sh -c 'mailcatcher …"   16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes   0.0.0.0:57365->1025/tcp, 0.0.0.0:57366->1080/tcp   parkservice-mailer-1
```

Comment: A webhook is where the Stripe server will fire a call to your url/api endpint. Phpfpm:9000 is not a valid domain. I usually use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) when testing webhooks locally.

Comment: ty it worked with ngrok